# How Do I apply these settings to more than one sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to apply these settings to more than one sheet but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

```
Public Sub FormatCostcode()
    Dim HeaderRow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    HeaderRow = 4
    With shDSMaster
        .Range("A:A,B:B").ClearFormats
        .Range("A" & HeaderRow, "B" & HeaderRow).Interior.Color = 13285804
        .Range("A" & HeaderRow, "B" & HeaderRow).Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
        For i = HeaderRow To HeaderRow + GetCostcodeRange - 1
               .Range("B" & i).Font.FontStyle = "bold"
               .Range("A" & i).BorderAround , xlThin
               .Range("B" & i).BorderAround , xlThin
            If .Range("C" & i).Value = "Surgical" Then
               .Range("B" & i).Interior.Color = 15773696
               .Range("A" & i).Interior.Color = 15773696
            ElseIf .Range("C" & i).Value = "Critical Care" Or .Range("C" & i).Value = "Medical 1" Then
               .Range("B" & i).Interior.Color = 9359529
               .Range("A" & i).Interior.Color = 9359529
            ElseIf .Range("C" & i).Value = "Medical 2" Then
               .Range("B" & i).Interior.Color = 14842064
               .Range("A" & i).Interior.Color = 14842064
            ElseIf .Range("C" & i).Value = "NICU and Womens' Health" Then
               .Range("B" & i).Interior.Color = 16735231
               .Range("A" & i).Interior.Color = 16735231
            ElseIf .Range("C" & i).Value = "Others" Then
               .Range("B" & i).Interior.Color = 8696052
               .Range("A" & i).Interior.Color = 8696052
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

I have Tried using With shDSmaster and shSlave but it does not seem to work. these are the codenames as I have changed the generic sheet1/sheet2

Comment: Afaik you can't do this in one go, you could have it in a loop (through the sheets of the workbook or something similar) where you change the sheet variable to the ones you want.

Comment: I see, i'll have a go at it. thank you.

Comment: I do hope you're declaring your variables properly in the full code, wouldn't want VBA to assume things ;) Use `Option Explicit` so you don't miss any (Tools -> Options -> check "Require variable declaration" -> OK)

Comment: I am still learning but I do my best. :D and yes, I do have option explicit enabled. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the sheet reference to the procedure and run the procedure twice.

```
Public Sub Main()

    FormatCostcode shDSMaster 'Pass shDSMaster as the TargetSheet
    FormatCostcode shSlave

End Sub


Public Sub FormatCostcode(TargetSheet As Worksheet)
    Dim HeaderRow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    HeaderRow = 4
    With TargetSheet
        .Range("A:A,B:B").ClearFormats
        .Range("A" & HeaderRow, "B" & HeaderRow).Interior.Color = 13285804
        .Range("A" & HeaderRow, "B" & HeaderRow).Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
        For i = HeaderRow To HeaderRow + GetCostcodeRange - 1
               .Range("B" & i).Font.FontStyle = "bold"
               .Range("A" & i).BorderAround , xlThin
               .Range("B" & i).BorderAround , xlThin
            If .Range("C" & i).Value = "Surgical" Then
               .Range("B" & i).Interior.Color = 15773696
               .Range("A" & i).Interior.Color = 15773696
            ElseIf .Range("C" & i).Value = "Critical Care" Or .Range("C" & i).Value = "Medical 1" Then
               .Range("B" & i).Interior.Color = 9359529
               .Range("A" & i).Interior.Color = 9359529
            ElseIf .Range("C" & i).Value = "Medical 2" Then
               .Range("B" & i).Interior.Color = 14842064
               .Range("A" & i).Interior.Color = 14842064
            ElseIf .Range("C" & i).Value = "NICU and Womens' Health" Then
               .Range("B" & i).Interior.Color = 16735231
               .Range("A" & i).Interior.Color = 16735231
            ElseIf .Range("C" & i).Value = "Others" Then
               .Range("B" & i).Interior.Color = 8696052
               .Range("A" & i).Interior.Color = 8696052
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly. There's so much I need to learn.